# treat object as entity or value object?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Iam working on small booking room system. In my solution I have a Reservation (Entity) which holds reference to ReservationTerm (value object).

Reservation term is of 3 types - simple reservation term (which stands for simple from-to); period reservation term (which stands for period repetition); and composite term (which should aggregate forementioned terms);

[image]

And here is my problem. I dont know if i should treat `ReservationTerm` as object with identity or only value object. For me its  importatnt to read values from it, but, i dont know how its gonna behave when I try to aggregate other `ReservationTerms` with `CompositeTerm`.

Comment: Apart from your title, do you have a question?

Comment: yes , the question is should i treat reservationTerm as value object or entity object in my context?

Comment: Then please edit your question and add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only can a value object can hold another value object, it can hold entities.

In terms of how you model `ReservationTerm` - does it have an identity of its own or can it be fully described by its state? If the former, it should be an entity, if the latter, a value type.

Comment: it does not have any identity. primary fields and values in it are primarly important for me

Comment: @Ivan - So it is a value object. If you don't need to track it and it doesn't have an identity of its own, model it as a value object.